# The compression parameter is set in the external_data_configuration block even though I didn't set it

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create a table based on gsheet in BigQuery and I'm using the resource google_bigquery_table. Here is my code and as you can see I don't define the compression parameter:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "external_table" {
  dataset_id = "dataset_test"
  table_id   = "external_table_test"

  external_data_configuration {
    autodetect    = true
    source_format = "GOOGLE_SHEETS"
    ignore_unknown_values = false

    google_sheets_options {
      skip_leading_rows = 1
      range = local.table_range
    }
    source_uris = [local.external_table_uri]
  }
  deletion_protection = false
}
```

Here is a screenshot from BQ and this parameter is set. How can I force this parameter not to be set when deploying code from Terraform ?

[External table configuration after being created by terraform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cyin.png)

I was trying to change it and the only way I came up with was creating the table in BQ  like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `project_id.dataset_test.external_table_test`
OPTIONS(
  sheet_range="table_range",
  skip_leading_rows=1,
  format="GOOGLE_SHEETS",
  uris=[""]
);
```

and then in BQ it looks like this:

[External table configuration after being created by SQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R73f4.png)

That is a temporary solution, but I'm trying to create this table from terraform with this resource google_bigquery_table. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you want to have the `external_data_configuration` block or not? Doesn't `NONE` mean there is no compression?

Comment: I want to use external_data_configuration block. In the documentation this parameter appears as optional, so I assume that it shouldn't appear when I do terraform plan.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table.html

Comment: Optional does not mean it's not set by default to a certain value, it just means you are not required to provide it when using the resource.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I updated my question. Do you know if there is possible to have the same configuration as you can see in the second picture but when we create it from Terraform?